# JBoss AS EAP versions - What parts of EAP source code are closed source?

Tags: jboss, eap

Question about the source code for JBoss EAP versions 4 5 or 6.

Let's say we decided to purchase JBoss EAP 6 from RedHat. Can we still run maven to build JBoss EAP version? Are there closed source resources involved?

Basically we are worried that going with the EAP version will limit our ability to utilize JBoss as an Open Source tool.

I would imagine there is closed source involved. Otherwise, for example, people would be able to take the patches from JBoss EAP 4.3 and then apply them to JBoss 4.2.3.GA community version. Or am I mistaken?

Please see this reference: JBoss Enterprise Application Platform Component Details https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/articles/112673 - Describes each open source JBoss component utilized from JBoss AS EAP version. But what it does not describe is patches etc that are applied.

Answer (score 0):

There is no closed source nature to EAP or any Red Hat products. When you purchase a subscription from Red Hat you get access to the product and its source code in its entirety. From the link you have provided, you will notice that it lists all of the platform components bundled with EAP & the community version which was taken.

The software development cycle at Red Hat means that they take these community projects and enhance the various components to ensure they meet a standard of robustness, security, stability which is suitable for Enterprise implementation. All enhancements made to the product are then given back to the community & their various projects so that they can incorporate these into later versions. A majority of Open Source projects/products are licensed under the GPL License, meaning that any changes or additions made to the software must be given back to the community.

As for building EAP through maven, could you elaborate on this? EAP comes pre-packaged, ready to go out of the box, you simply have to unzip, configure & deploy to a location of your choice, then deploy your application and away you go. EAP or any Red Hat product does not require any Maven Build process in order to use it.

If you have any concerns, please contact Red Hat's Sales teams who will be more than happy to got into more detail about the Open Source nature of Red Hat & its products.

Comment: Do you happen to work for *Red Hat*, by the way?